# Set an ID based on a pattern and another variable on a dataframe [pandas]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If a have this dataframe

```
    time_diff   value
0   0.00123     1
1   0.00320     2
2   0.00300     1
3   0.00500     5   
4   0.00700     1
5   0.80000     2
6   0.00200     1
7   0.00400     3
8   0.00200     1
9   0.00020     3
10  0.00200     1
11  0.00500     3
12  0.01200     2
13  0.00200     4
14  0.00200     5
```

I want to define an ID based on some parameters:

1. we must have a repetition in the `value` field. For example: `a-b-a-b-a` or `a-b-a-c-a` (that is, you should always go back to the first item and end with it)

**AND**

2. the `time_diff` field must be less than 0.01

So, based only in the `value`, we will have

```
    value   ID
0   1       0
1   2       0
2   1       0
3   5       0
4   1       0
5   2       0
6   1       0
7   3       0
8   1       0
9   3       0
10  1       0
11  3       1
12  2       2
13  4       3
14  5       4
```

and based on `time_diff`

```
    time_diff   ID
0   0.00123     0
1   0.00320     0
2   0.00300     0
3   0.00500     0
4   0.00700     0
5   0.80000     1
6   0.00200     1
7   0.00400     1
8   0.00200     1
9   0.00020     1
10  0.00200     1
11  0.00500     1
12  0.01200     2
13  0.00200     2
14  0.00200     2
```

So, the final output will be

```
    time_diff   value   ID
0   0.00123     1       0
1   0.00320     2       0
2   0.00300     1       0
3   0.00500     5       0
4   0.00700     1       0
5   0.80000     2       1
6   0.00200     1       2
7   0.00400     3       2
8   0.00200     1       2
9   0.00020     3       2
10  0.00200     1       2
11  0.00500     3       3
12  0.01200     2       4
13  0.00200     4       5
14  0.00200     5       6
```

Can anyone help me with this?